# What is the probability that I would wait more than 5min for the bus?

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

I'm waiting at a bus stop, I can take the bus 34, which I need to wait for, on average, 10 min, and the bus 45, which I need to wait for, on average 4 minutes. The times of arrival of the buses are assumed to be independent.

What is the probability that I would wait more than 5min.

**My Attempt**

I'm not sure how having two buses affect the probability, but I know I could represent them separately as exponential distributions.

Bus 34: Our exponential distribution parameter is $\lambda=\frac{1}{10}$. Our p.d.f. is:

\begin{equation}
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{10}e^{-\frac{x}{10}} &\text{if } x\geq0\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Integrating from $0$ to $t$ gives us our c.d.f.
$$F(t)=1-e^{-\frac{t}{10}}$$

Bus 45: Our exponential distribution parameter is $\lambda=\frac{1}{4}$. Our p.d.f. is:

\begin{equation}
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{4}e^{-\frac{x}{4}} &\text{if } x\geq0\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Integrating from $0$ to $t$ gives us our c.d.f.
$$F(t)=1-e^{-\frac{t}{4}}$$

Then the probability of waiting over five minutes for bus 34 is $$\mathbb{P}(X>5)=1-\mathbb{P}(x\leq 5)=1-F(5)=1-(1-e^{-\frac{5}{10}})=0.6065$$
and the probability of waiting over five minutes for bus 45 is
$$\mathbb{P}(X>5)=1-\mathbb{P}(x\leq 5)=1-F(5)=1-(1-e^{-\frac{5}{4}})=0.2865$$

My thinking is that the probability that you wait more than $5$ minutes is the average of these two probabilities, but I was told that this is wrong. Can I get some pointers on how to approach this problem?

Comment: Given that the buses are independent, the probability that you have to wait more than five minutes for a bus is the product of the probabilities that you have to wait at least that long for either bus.  That's because you "win" only if you have to wait more than five minutes for Bus $34$ and you also have to wait more than five minutes for Bus $45$.